# VBA loop through array string element issue

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, string, loops

Due to simple loop though Variant array I notice if value code "SALA_1000" it's seems like compiler doesn't see element , so condition Element = prevElement never happen for this value. What is the reason of such behavior? It's interesting if I change To Sala_1000, or SAla_1000 or add space it works fine. Does Sala_1000 mean something special in VBA?
[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d07eD.png)

Data:

| ID | Code |
| --- | --- |
| A001 | HRLY_1001 |
| A002 | SALA_1000 |
| A003 | SALA_1000 |
| A004 | HRLY_1001 |
| A005 | SALA_1000 |

```
Sub CheckSome()

  Dim fc As Range
  Dim Tbl As Range
  Dim DataArr() As Variant
  
  Dim i As Long

  Dim Element As String
  Dim prevElement As String
  

  Set fc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(What:="code")
  Set Tbl = fc.CurrentRegion

  'assign range data to array
  DataArr = Tbl
  
  'looping through array
  For i = 1 To UBound(DataArr)
    
    'make "key": ID & code & Amount
    Element = CStr(DataArr(i, 1)) & CStr(DataArr(i, 2))
    
    'check if Element = prevElement
    If Element = prevElement Then
      
    Debug.Print DataArr(i, 2)
    
    Else
    
    Debug.Print "ok"
     
    End If
     
    prevElement = Element
  Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You're making a key of ID (unique in your test case) and Code which in itself makes every Element unique so I'm quite surprised you'd say it works perfectly fine if you change the Code-values a bit, i.e. A002SALA_1000 is different from A003SALA_1000

Comment: Even if looping only through code column - still weird behavior

Comment: I used your example data, ran your code with an intersect on the b-column so your "Tbl" is only B1:B6 (only through code column), removed the `& CStr(DataArr(i, 2))` (could also just use `CStr(DataArr(i, 1))` without the intersect ofc) and got into the `If Element = prevElement` clause just fine. Your code is working as intended since you're making a unique key. If you want to check if the codes are the same, you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the placement of prevElement = Element at the end of the loop, the Debug.Print DataArr(i, 2) statement within the If Element = prevElement condition may not execute as expected.
Because Element = CStr(DataArr(i, 1)) & CStr(DataArr(i, 2)) assigns a new ID to "SALA_1000."

To see the output of Debug.Print DataArr(i, 2), I would put Debug.Print statement above the line prevElement = Element.

```
Else
    
    Debug.Print "ok"
     
    End If
    
    Debug.Print DataArr(i, 2)
    prevElement = Element
  Next i

End Sub
```